# Delete object of my domain in a hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Using Grails I build these domains:

```
class Book {
    String title
}

class Author {
    String name

    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}


def book1 = new Book(title: "The Shining")

def author1 = new Author(name: "Stephen King")
author1.addToBooks(book1)
```

If try to delete `author1`:

```
author1.books.clear()
author1.delete flush:true
```

I get this error:

> Message
>       null Caused by
>       Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKQG8TLCGMC6WKG6ILECFOXSLVS: PUBLIC.PROJECT_BOOK FOREIGN
>   KEY(BOOK_AUTHOR_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PROJECT_AUTHOR(ID) (1)"; SQL
>   statement: delete from project_column where id=? and version=?
>   [23503-195]

I would like to delete an author without deleting the books.

Comment: You have modelled an author has manyBooks so therefore all the books are bound to the author. If you delete the author the books will belong to ? as in it is broken data at that point so hence it is correct

Comment: If i delete the author, the books must continue to exist

Comment: I did not use belongto

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463196/how-to-prevent-from-grails-not-to-delete-child-while-deleting-parent same question as this

Answer (score 0):

In short it isn't really good practise what you are trying to do:

you can declare a mapping like:

```
static mapping={
// This is how you tell hibernate to remove all records so you will need the reverse of this
  //books cascade:'all-delete-orphan'
  //possible this - you will need to experiment
  books cascade: 'none'
}
```

But maybe you should declare it very differently

```
class Book {
    String title
    Long autorId

    Author getAuthor() {
       return Authoer.get(authorId)
    }
}

class Author {
    String name

    List<Books> getBooks() {
      return Books.findAllByAuthorId(this.id)
    }
}
```

That way there is no real relationship between book or author beyond your own id mapping so rather than doing all that `addToBooks` you create author you create book and you set `book.authoriId=author.id`

The rest of it is looked up dynamically through your queries when you forward walk through your classes.

Down side is it is not direct relations so HQL queries etc become a little more complex

There is also which you haven't suggested there is a declaration of:

```
static belongsTo = [author:Author]
```

which could make it a looser relation to:

```
static belongsTo = Author
```

Typically though if you have this hasMany relationship this behaviour is what kicks in when you try to remove nested relations it isn't something new

Comment: I did not use belongto

Answer (score 0):

By default, a `hasMany` relationship adds a database column to the 'many' side of the relationship. This means each of your `Books` has a column to store the `author`. To change that you can define a join table instead.

```
static mapping = {
    books joinTable: [name: 'author_books',
                      key: 'author_id',
                      column: 'book_id']
}
```

This will create a table to store the relationship, so deleting the author won't need to touch the individual books.